# Tikz flowchart unusual arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I used the `tikzpicture` environment to generate the following figure. I am not happy with the arrow generated on the extreme left that arrows going from the box of `${\bf{Spectral Curve}}$` to `${\bf{Quantum curve}}$` and vice versa. I give my code here below. If some modification can be suggested it would be helpful.

[image]

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
[block/.style={rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm,draw}]
\label{Qflow}
\node[block] (1) {spectral curve\\ $$ A(x,y)=0$$};
\node[block,  right=-.5 and 2 of 1] (3) {correlation differential $\omega_{g,n}$};
\node[block,  right=-.5 and 2 of 3] (5) {Free Energy};
\node[block, below=of 5] (6) {Partition Function};
\node[block, left=-.5 and 2 of 6] (4) {Schr\"{o}dinger equation};
\node[block, left=-.5 and 2 of 4] (2) {Quantum curve};

\begin{scope}[->, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm]

\draw (1) to[out=0,in=180] (3);
\draw (3) to[out=0,in=180] (5);
\draw (5) -- (6);
\draw (2) -- (1);
\draw (1) to[out=180,in=180] (2);


\draw (4) to[out=180,in=0] (2);
\draw (6) to[out=180,in=0] (4);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please make your example a complete LaTeX document, with the minimum necessary for us to reproduce your figure. It must start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks, I see you have already and placed with the latex environment. I did not know how to do it before.

Comment: Right, but did you read my comment? Please edit your post and provide us with a minimal document that we can simply copy/paste (i.e., a complete document) in order to compile it and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are more satisfied with one of the following solutions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[block/.style={rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm,draw}]
\label{Qflow}
\node[block] (1) {spectral curve $A(x,y)=0$};
\node[block,  right=-.5 and 2 of 1] (3) {correlation differential $\omega_{g,n}$};
\node[block,  right=-.5 and 2 of 3] (5) {Free Energy};
\node[block, below=of 5] (6) {Partition Function};
\node[block, below=of 3] (4) {Schr\"{o}dinger equation};
\node[block, below=of 1] (2) {Quantum curve};

\begin{scope}[->, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm]

\draw (1) -- (3);
\draw (3) -- (5);
\draw (5) -- (6);
\draw (2) -- (1);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=1em}] (1) -- (2);
\draw (4) -- (2);
\draw (6) -- (4);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
[block/.style={rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, text width=2cm, align=center,draw}]
\label{Qflow}
\node[block] (1) {spectral curve $A(x,y)=0$};
\node[block,  right=-.5 and 2 of 1] (3) {correlation differential $\omega_{g,n}$};
\node[block,  right=-.5 and 2 of 3] (5) {Free Energy};
\node[block, below=of 5] (6) {Partition Function};
\node[block, below=of 3] (4) {Schr\"{o}dinger equation};
\node[block, below=of 1] (2) {Quantum curve};

\begin{scope}[->, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm]

\draw (1) -- (3);
\draw (3) -- (5);
\draw (5) -- (6);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-0.5em}] (2) -- (1);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=0.5em}] (1) -- (2);
\draw (4) -- (2);
\draw (6) -- (4);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
[block/.style={rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, text width=2cm, align=center,draw}]
\label{Qflow}
\node[block] (1) {spectral curve $A(x,y)=0$};
\node[block,  right= of 1] (3) {correlation differential $\omega_{g,n}$};
\node[block,  right= of 3] (5) {Free Energy};
\node[block, below=of 5] (6) {Partition Function};
\node[block, below=of 3] (4) {Schr\"{o}dinger equation};
\node[block, below=of 1] (2) {Quantum curve};

\begin{scope}[->, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm]

\draw (1) -- (3);
\draw (3) -- (5);
\draw (5) -- (6);
\draw (2) -- (1);
\draw (1) to[out=180,in=180] (2);
\draw (4) -- (2);
\draw (6) -- (4);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```